# Can my AL halfling ranger have a pteranodon animal companion?

Tags: dnd-5e, ranger, animal-companions, dnd-adventurers-league

Is it Adventurers League legal for a halfling ranger to use the Pteranodon as an animal companion in Eberron where halflings routinely ride dinosaurs?

Comment: Hello and welcome! You can take the [tour] for a quick site intro (and a badge!). The dnd-5e tag has been added to the question to note the system used. Happy gaming!

Comment: @SevenSidedDie just as a note, the above comment concerning Eberron appears to be incorrect. They have indeed released Eberron AL rules now [here](https://www.dmsguild.com/m/product/208178). Given that, I'm not sure further clarification is needed.

Answer (score 11):

### Yes, per RAW a ranger can have pteranodon as his/her animal companion.

The two prerequisites for a ranger's animal companion are (PHB  page 93):

> "... a beast that is no larger than **Medium** [emphasis mine] and has a challenge rating **[CR] of 1/4** [emphasis mine] or lower..."

A pteranodon satisfies both of those requirements.

Also relevant to address the AL part of your question is this quote from the [AL FAQ v8.2](https://www.dmsguild.com/m/product/208178) on page 6:

> Creatures with **complete stat blocks** found in the *Monster Manual* and other resources listed in the ALCC are available for use with class features such as Wild Shape, **Beast Companion** [emphasis mine], and various *conjure* spells, keeping in mind that your Dungeon Master is the **final** arbiter for the rules, such as determining whether or not your character has satisfied requirements such as those imposed upon you by your class (such as the druid’s requirement to have seen the beast in question).

Per this reference, you may certainly use the *Monster Manual* as a legal resource and the pteranodon from it as your companion. It would also appear that there are no class requirements imposed by the ranger's Beast Companion ability that you must meet to select it.

Comment: Correction I was wrong about Eberron. I had not realized it was released yet. You have to [go here](https://www.dmsguild.com/m/product/208178) for the full rules, not just the FAQ. If there is no further restriction there, it might be helpful to note that using this familiar would be their PHB+1 source.

Comment: I have updated your answer with the current wording of the rule from the current FAQ. I don't know why WotC continues to link to an old version, but the only current versions now are only ever on the DMsguild (in the link in my comment above). I don't think it changes your answer substantially.

Comment: Great answer! You may want to include that they'll likely need an [exotic saddle](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/134561/are-saddles-required-to-ride-flying-mounts) to ride one.