# Can a beholderkin summoned with Summon Aberration be used as a flying mount?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, mount, flight

If I cast *Summon Aberration* to summon a Beholderkin, would I be able to stand or sit/mount it and have it fly?

Answer (score 4):

#### It's up to the DM, and your size must be small.

The rules for [Mounted Combat](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#MountedCombat) state:

> A willing creature that is at least *one size larger than you and that has an appropriate anatomy* can serve as a mount, using the following rules.

Since *summon aberration* summons a medium sized beholderkin, this is only possible if you are playing a size small race. If you are medium, this just doesn't work. If you are small, and the DM determines that a beholderkin has the appropriate anatomy, then this works just fine, but it is the DM's decision. If allowed, the usual rules for mounts should be followed.

Comment: Your DM's ruling on this may depend on their memories of [hopper balls](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=hopper+ball)

Comment: It might be good to spell out that [an exotic saddle is required to ride any flying mount](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/134561/48191), as in my experience this rule is often missed.